# How can we get an iterator which ignores missing libraries, such as `crypt`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we use pip to install `stdlib_list` and execute the following, then we get an error message:

```
import importlib
import itertools as itts
from stdlib_list import stdlib_list

def get_modules():
    module_names = iter(stdlib_list("3.7"))
    libs         = map(importlib.import_module, module_names)
    builtins     = dir(__builtins__)
    return  itts.chain(libs, builtins)

modules = get_modules()
for module in modules:
    pass
```

The error message:

```
ImportError: The crypt module is not supported on Windows
```

How can a create an iterator which silently moves onto the next result?

Comment: Is the issue that you need something in the `crypt` library, or do you want `get_modules` to ignore `crypt` on Windows?

Comment: @Ry- I want something like `get_modules` exception that it ignores `crypt` and other missing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `ImportError`:

```
def try_import_module(name):
    try:
        return importlib.import_module(name)
    except ImportError:
        return None
```

then:

```
def get_modules():
    module_names = stdlib_list("3.7")
    libs         = filter(None, map(try_import_module, module_names))
    builtins     = dir(__builtins__)
    return itts.chain(libs, builtins)
```